# How to use ghprb Jenkins env vars?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I use Multibranch Pipeline job which is working very well. 
I also use GitHub pull request builder plugin which makes some very useful environment variables available.

ghprbActualCommit
ghprbActualCommitAuthor
ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail
ghprbPullDescription
ghprbPullId
ghprbPullLink
ghprbPullTitle
ghprbSourceBranch
ghprbTargetBranch
sha1

But I can't access them, when I print env variables, they are not set.

Can someone suggest how to access these?

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of the above mentioned Environment variables by writing them in this format ==>  ${ghprbActualCommitAuthor}

let us suppose person **Jack** is the commit author
at runtime you will be given the value of this variable as **Jack**, you can apply further logic in this and do marvels in Jenkins.

:)